# Counting instance of a string in a Google Sheets range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a few sheets available to me and I'm currently making a dashboard-esque sheet that just displays quick facts about the data as a whole.

Before I explain what I'm trying to do, I will share examples of my two main sheets

#### Sheet1

| Name | Rarity |
| --- | --- |
| Item #1 | Rare |
| Item #2 | Epic |
| Item #3 | Epic |
| Item #4 | Common |
| Item #5 | Legendary |
| Item #6 | Rare |

#### Sheet2

| Item | Some check | Another check | So on | and so on... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item #1 | A | A |  | B |
| Item #2 |  | A | B | A |
| Item #3 | B |  | A | A |
| Item #4 |  | B | A | A |
| Item #5 |  | A |  |  |
| Item #6 | A |  | A | A |

This sheet currently has 12 columns after the `Item` but this *will* increase in future.

So what I'm trying to do is to get the item(s) of a specific rarity that has the most of a specific string in sheet 2. I'm able to filter the items by rarity using `FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B2:B = "Rare")`. I'm then able to use that filtered list to get the corresponding rows of sheet 2 with:
`FILTER(Sheet2!A2:E, COUNTIF(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B2:B = "Rare"), Sheet2!A2:A))`

What I can't figure out now is how to get the count of each instance of the text *per row*. Wrapping that last formula in a `COUNTIF()` just counts all of them together.

What I'd like to get to is a table where the first column is a list of rare items, with the second column being a list of the count (as below). From there I can simply run a filter on it checking if the count is equal to the `MAX()`.

| Item | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Item #1 | 2 |
| Item #6 | 3 |

Given what I have thus far, how do I get to where I want to be? How do I count each instance of the text per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a formula that filters the data the way you need, you can just apply a `byrow()` lambda to get the first value in each row, together with the count of the rest of the items in the row, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  filter( Sheet2!A2:E, countif( filter(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B2:B = "Rare"), Sheet2!A2:A ) ), 
  lambda( 
    row, 
    { index(row, 1, 1), counta(row) - 1 } 
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect for my needs. I was unaware of `BYROW`'s existence. I did need to change `COUNTA(row) - 1` to `COUNTIF(row, "A")` however. This may be a stupid question but my brain is mush at this point; if I were to wrap that in a `FILTER`, how do I reference the second returned column for the condition? I hadn't considered the condition would need to be a virtual range.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out with another `BYROW`. Not sure if it's the best way but it works :)